# WDA is getting Uninstalled but not getting installed | Xcode-13.4.1 (not Latest), appium 1.22 | Error xcodebuild failed with code 65

Tags: xcode, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium-ios

I am using **appium 1.22** on Latest Mac.
I am using older version of **Xcode(13.4.1)** on Mac (*there is a latest version of Xcode which Appium do not support* got this piece of info from someone known)

*I am using normal company which is not paid apple acount.*

Using this xcode 13.4.1, When  we  run WDA and build and Test which installs WDA on Device and it opens the simulator and installs WDA.

Now it launches the Simulator Install my IOS app and *uninstalls WDA*.
***but it DOES NOT install it again.***
then we got error

remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error:

```
Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure:
xcodebuild failed with code 65
```

***complete error:***

> ```
> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details.
> ```
>
> Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing
> the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because
> of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65
>
> ```
> xcodebuild error message:
>
>
>
> Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
>
> System info: host: '192.168.1.4', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:400:de8d:f8ab:9871%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch:
> ```
>
> 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
>
> ```
> Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
>
> remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to
> ```
>
> launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed
> with code 65
>
> ```
> xcodebuild error message:
>
>
>
>     at getResponseForW3CError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:804:9)
>
>     at asyncHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:380:37)
>
> Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
>
> System info: host: '192.168.1.4', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:400:de8d:f8ab:9871%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch:
> ```
>
> 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
>
> ```
> Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
>
>
>
> at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:216)
>
> at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:225)
>
> at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:250)
>
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
>
> at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
>
> at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>
> at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)
>
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
>
> at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:363)
>
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>
> at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
>
> at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:89)
>
> at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:99)
>
> at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.<init>(IOSDriver.java:90)
>
> at com.qa.utils.DriverManager.initializeDriver(DriverManager.java:34)
>
> at com.qa.runners.MyRunnerTest.initialize(MyRunnerTest.java:41)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>
> at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
>
> at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>
> at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
>
> at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.invokeMethod(RunBefores.java:33)
>
> at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
>
> at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
>
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
>
> at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>
> at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
>
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
>
> at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
>
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
>
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
>
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>
> at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:193)
>
> ... 34 more
>
> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original
> ```
>
> error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure:
> xcodebuild failed with code 65
>
> ```
> xcodebuild error message:
>
>
>
> Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
>
> System info: host: '192.168.1.4', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:400:de8d:f8ab:9871%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch:
> ```
>
> 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
>
> ```
> Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
>
> remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to
> ```
>
> launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed
> with code 65
>
> ```
> xcodebuild error message:
>
>
>
>     at getResponseForW3CError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:804:9)
>
>     at asyncHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:380:37)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
>
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
>
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
>
> at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>
> at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
>
> at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
>
> at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
>
> at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
>
> at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>
> at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
>
> at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>
> at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
>
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
> ```